# Where can I ask questions regarding video editing?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site where questions about video editing (adobe premiere cs6) would be on topic. I was thinking about posting it on Graphic Design but I don't think it really fits there.

My question if you need more details:

> My videos export in undesirable resolution and I just wonder if there is any way to fix that. (original video is 480x800 and it exports as 720x480) and even if I force it export as 480x800 there is just tons of black space around a video that's much smaller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) sounds appropriate for you.